# Kanji reading: 一人KY、実？中

Tags: kanji, meaning

This morning I took this picture, finding the `一人KY` poster amusing:

[image]

**QUESTION:** What is the kanji before `中` ?

In [Gjiten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gjiten) I can't find it by combining the radicals of 止 and 残, nor by number of strokes (17?) plus 止 radical.

I guess the poster says "If you don't pay attention to your environment, you are at risk" (which the side text あなた自身があなたを守る says too), but knowing the kanji would confirm or infirm this hypothesis.

Comment: 践 is under 足 rather than 止.

Comment: @Flaw I think in this case, KY stands for [危険予知](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%B1%E9%99%BA%E4%BA%88%E7%9F%A5)

Comment: My vote is for 危険予知 given the context and hardhat guy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It says 一人KY実践中

The word you're looking for, 実践{じっせん}, means "put into practice." You were having trouble finding this because it's 足 on the left, not 止. The meaning depends on what 一人KY is. As user snailplane points out, it likely means 危険予知{きけんよち}, which would give the phrase 一人KY実践中 the meaning of "Individual disaster readiness/prevention/preparedness in effect," or something more elegant along those lines.

The right side text, あなた自身があなたを守る, means "you (have to) protect yourself." The stuff on the far left and far right seem irrelevant, although I'm not sure which side text you're referring to.

Comment: Very interesting! I was convinced KY meant 空気読めない and did not though this other meaning. I clarified the part were I was referring to a side text.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this kind of poster on a construction site too. It was written something like :
現地KYをしろ！
However as I did not know the expression 危険予知, I assumed it meant 空気読め, which made sense in a way, if we consider it can mean "be aware of your surroundings", maybe intended as a pun.

By the way here is a Yahoo discussion about the expression, where the "best answer" is in favor of 危険予知 :
 http://m.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q1312627248

Comment: I think that the abbreviation KY for 危険予知, [which dates back at least to 1990](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/489782172X), is older than the abbreviation KY for 空気読めない, and therefore the former is probably not intended to be a pun.